# How to call sequential variables with for loop matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of variables called `length_act_i` where

```
i=1:6
```

I'd like to call each one sequentially as part of a for loop, but this doesn't work:

```
for i=1:6
    I={['length_act_',num2str(i)]};
    subplot(3,2,i)
    [f x]=hist(I,1:2:5);
    bar(x,f./trapz(x,f),'barwidth',0.5,'r');
end
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Regards,

Comment: do you want to load `length_act_i`?

Comment: Using i as a variable name is bad practice, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab

Comment: @Shai yes that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) inside your loop:

```
eval(['I = length_act_', num2str(i)]);
```

**Pro tip:**
The `eval` command is usually slow and inefficient, use arrays instead. In your case, it seems that each of your "length_act_i" variables is a vector on its own, so you should be employing a cell array. For instance, call it `length_act` and set it like so:

```
length_act = {length_act_1, length_act_2, length_act_3, ...};
```

and then access each cell in the array using:

```
for i = 1:length(length_act)
    I = length_act{i};

    ...
end
```

Also, [it is recommended not to use "i" and "j" as names for variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: +1 for decrypting this question.

Comment: +1 for being faster...

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you. I've been using all sorts of makeshift methods of accessing and storing data but never properly understood one method over another. It also solved another question of how to add different length vectors to a single array. Amazingly quick too! :)

Comment: Actually, a quick question. If I had 1000 vectors length_act_1...1000 how would you efficiently pop them into length_act?

Comment: @user1134241 You should be generating `length_act` _instead_ of creating 1000 variables. If you cannot modify your code accordingly, resort to `eval`.